# Memory leak in Bukkit plugin

Tags: java, memory-leaks, minecraft, bukkit

In my Spigot plugin I update the player's inventory every 0.5 seconds using a repeating task. After running the code for a longer period of time I would get a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.

I did some debugging and used JProfiler to see what was causing memory leaks, and noticed an ever increasing number of ItemStacks. The heap walker showed that this was caused by the code updating the inventory. This is the current code:

```
public void updateInventory(Collection<? extends Player> players) {
    for (int i = 0; i < guiSize; i++) {
        ItemStack itemStack;
        if (serverItems.containsKey(i)) {
            itemStack = serverItems.get(i);
        } else {
            short color = GLASS_PANE_COLORS[RANDOM.nextInt(GLASS_PANE_COLORS.length - 1)];
            itemStack = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, color);
            ItemMeta itemMeta = itemStack.getItemMeta();
            itemMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RESET + "");
            itemStack.setItemMeta(itemMeta);
        }

        for (Player player : players) {
            player.getOpenInventory().getTopInventory().setItem(i, itemStack);
        }
    }
}
```

After some more debugging I found out that removing the line `player.getOpenInventory().getTopInventory().setItem(i, itemStack)` would stop the increasing number of ItemStacks.

What could cause this memory leak?

Edit:

I have changed te code to not make a new ItemStack for every single glass pane. Instead it now stores all the colours in a Map and gets an ItemStack from that map, to put into the inventory. This still does not work and the server will crash with an OOME after a while.

Comment: There's no memory leak here, it will only create `guiSize` ItemStacks.

Comment: What would cause the huge number of ItemStacks shown in JProfiler then? If I removed this code it was gone.

Comment: It would be caused by `guiSize` being large.

Comment: ```guiSize``` is always 27 in this case. The number of ItemStacks would go to 500.000 before showing OutOfMemoryErrors.

Comment: There's no reason why that would occur unless `updateInventory` was being called faster than the garbage collection of the local `ItemStack` variables.

Answer (score 0):

The given code appears to be correct in the sense that it does not contribute to observed memory leaks. While not shown, the subsequent modification to pre-generate ItemStacks - a better solution - would not contribute either.

However, are you aware that `getOpenInventory()` returns the inventory the player is currently viewing and if none are being viewed, returns the player's default view, which is their crafting inventory? Is there a pre-condition to your method that all players in the given collection have a certain inventory open? What happens if one or more players are currently viewing the inventory of an oven, dispenser, etc.? If you want to always access the player inventory, you should use `getInventory()`.

I ask because otherwise setting an item to a non-existing slot of a different inventory should cause other exceptions rather than your OOM, though I will not voucher for inventory bounds checks in Spigot or Minecraft. Thinking it might be, I briefly traced through the latest Spigot-Server code. Nothing stood out that would cause memory leaks.

Are other plugins loaded when you are testing? If so, disable all except those that your plugin may be dependent on.

I wish I could provide more insight, but there isn't much I can do with just a code snippet that would not take longer to investigate.